# iOS SDK: Custom open graph story with "Feelings"

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm successfully publishing a custom Open Graph story, with a custom `FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction` and a custom `FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject`.

However, I can't find the documentation for assigning a "feeling" to the story. There are a few questions here on SO but the answers say it's not possible, although the Runtastic iOS app does it (see the "feeling awesome" part):

[image]

I'm not using the standard Share Dialog (`FBSDKShareDialog`) but am implementing my own custom interface as advised in their [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios)

Has anyone had any success with this? Any thoughts/ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this feature is available in the SDKs or the API.